# Why running git stash under my ubuntu server I got Permission denied errors?

Tags: git, ubuntu

Running git stash under my ubuntu server I got errors :

```
ubuntu@ip-NN-NN-NN-NN : AWS Ubuntu Server :/var/www/html/tads$ git stash 
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 5cf9b22 Setting email gun
error: unable to unlink old '.editorconfig': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old '.env.example': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old '.gitattributes': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old '.gitignore': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old '.styleci.yml': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old '1.blade.php': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old '1.js': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old '1.php': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old '1.txt': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'README.md': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old '\': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'artisan': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'c': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'codepen.blade.php': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'composer.json': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'composer.lock': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'invalid.html': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'package.json': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'php': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'phpunit.xml': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'route_list.txt': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'server.php': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'tailwind.config.js': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'valid.html': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'webpack.mix.js': Permission denied
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.
ubuntu@ip-NN-NN-NN-NN : AWS Ubuntu Server :/var/www/html/tads$ cd ../
ubuntu@ip-NN-NN-NN-NN : AWS Ubuntu Server :/var/www/html$ ls -la
total 28
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root    4096 Jul 28 11:31 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    4096 Jul 28 11:21 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10918 Jul 28 11:21 index.html
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    3068 Jul 28 11:31 info.php
drwxr-xr-x 16  755 ubuntu  4096 Jul 28 14:42 tads
```

I am not sure but looks like it happened after reading some manuals I
tried to give permissions tro execute to ubuntu user under which I login in my server's console:

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu .
sudo chown 755 .
ls -la
...
drwxr-xr-x 16    755 ubuntu   4096 Jul 28 14:42  .
```

Was it reason and how it can be fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering `/var/www/html` folder and files are owned by root, it is not surprising that any command executed as ubuntu would fail.

Try at least the chown (that you have done under '`.`', but I don't know if your current folder was `/var/www/html`):

```
cd /var/www/html
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu .
```

Check the ownership then, and repeat your `git` command.

Check also:

- your environment variables for any `GIT_xxx` variables
- your aliases in case `git` itself is aliased
- `which git` in case `git` is wrapped by a custom script
- `/var/www/html/tags/.git`, to make sure the repository is directly under `tads`.